# Issue with $(document).ready

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, dynamic-content

I'v got two questions. First. How can I reduce this code?

```
$('#m').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load('inc/main.php').fadeIn('normal');
    return false;
});
$('#b').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load('inc/blog.php').fadeIn('normal'); 
    return false;
});
$('#p').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load('inc/portfolio.php').fadeIn('normal');    
    return false;
});
$('#l').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load('inc/lebenslauf.php').fadeIn('normal');   
    return false;
});
$('#k').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load('inc/kontakt.php').fadeIn('normal');  
    return false;
});
```

I'm using a lib called perfect scrollbar. It is included this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(a){a("#scrollbox").perfectScrollbar({wheelSpeed:20,wheelPropagation:!1})});
```

When main.php is loaded in with this script, the scrollbar is not there like it should be. It's because the document doesn't refresh like usual. What to I need to write to get it working when loaded in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function & pass each selector & filepath to this function

```
$('#m').click(some_function()
{
    helperfunction($(this), 'inc/main.php');
});

function helperfunction(selector, phpfilepath) {
    var href = selector.attr('href');
    $('#con').hide().load(phpfilepath).fadeIn('normal');    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm a js noob. I wouldn't ask if I knew an answer :-)

Comment: Alright Thanks. What am I gonna do with my second problem? $("#Demo").perfectScrollbar({
  wheelSpeed: 20,
  wheelPropagation: true
})

Comment: Not sure on that.. never worked with perfect scrollbar lib. Look at the CSS you have for the scrollbar & see if its rendering properly. Just guessing..